# Name pandas dataframe from a for loop with the use of range and the year in question

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I'm trying to get some data from a website, and the data consists of one Excel file per year (from 2015 to 2021). I feel I'm nearly done, but what is missing is to be able to save every annual result into a separate dataframe with a distinct name (with year as suffix). This probably have a simple solution and possibly there are other solutions to this, but what I am trying is twist the final row and dataframe in the code (df_long = ...) not to be named to df_long but df_long_2015, df_long_2016...etc as it goes through the for-loop. Thinking to concat all the years in the end. The problem now is that for every loop of year the df_long dataframe is overwritten, thus loosing the result of the previous year.  Appreciate any help...thanks.

```
for aar in range(2015,2021+1):
    print(aar)
    url = f'https://www.nordpoolgroup.com/48c8e5/globalassets/marketdata-excel-files/elspot-prices_{aar}_daily_nok.xls'
    liste = pd.read_html(url, parse_dates=True, decimal=',', thousands='.', header=2, index_col=0, encoding='UTF-8')
    
    df = pd.DataFrame(liste[0])
    df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, format = '%Y-%m-%d')
    
    df_long = df.stack().to_frame()
    df_long.reset_index(inplace=True)
    df_long.columns = ['Dato','Område','Pris']
    
    filt = df_long['Område'].isin(['Oslo','Bergen','Tr.heim','Tromsø','Kr.sand','Molde'])
    df_long = df_long.loc[filt, :]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will this work?

```py
df_list = []
for aar in range(2015,2021+1):
    print(aar)
    url = f'https://www.nordpoolgroup.com/48c8e5/globalassets/marketdata-excel-files/elspot-prices_{aar}_daily_nok.xls'
    liste = pd.read_html(url, parse_dates=True, decimal=',', thousands='.', header=2, index_col=0, encoding='UTF-8')
    
    df = pd.DataFrame(liste[0])
    df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, format = '%Y-%m-%d')
    
    df_long = df.stack().to_frame()
    df_long.reset_index(inplace=True)
    df_long.columns = ['Dato','Område','Pris']
    
    filt = df_long['Område'].isin(['Oslo','Bergen','Tr.heim','Tromsø','Kr.sand','Molde'])
    df_long = df_long.loc[filt, :]

    df_long['aar'] = aar
    df_list.append(df_long)

final_df = pd.concat(df_list)
```

Comment: So if I am not mistaken, you just made a list of dataframes which you appended on top of eact other...and added them up in the end through the concat step...it worked actually. Neat. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it's as simple as that. :)

Comment: However, dont' think I needed the df_long['aar'] = aar that you added - works well also without...

Comment: Yes, that's just in case, sometimes files do not contain any identifying columns, so I wasn't sure if that's the case for your data.

Answer (score 1):

Create an empty dictionary, add each dataframe to the dictionary with the name, e.g. df_long_2015, as the key and the dataframe as the value.

Comment: Possible this may also work, but how can you make the for-loop create the then names df_long_2015, df_long_2016 etc? A little unsure how to create the complete dataframe name here automatically through my coding mentioned earlier...somehow I must combine df_long_ with the variable aar (meaning year e.g. 2015) which is derrived from the loop...but how?